# Why does PageSpeed Insights report "page reached the limit of 3 client redirects" when site is not redirecting?

Tags: redirect, pagespeed

After submitting a url to [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/), I get the following response:

> Attempting to load the page reached the limit of 3 client redirects. The last URL fetched was [url removed]. This may indicate the page is redirecting to itself, or has a loop of redirects.

Yet I can't find any other evidence that there actually are any redirects. Submitting the same url to [Redirect Detective](http://redirectdetective.com/) or using a browser extension like [Redirect Path](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirect-path/aomidfkchockcldhbkggjokdkkebmdll) finds no redirects at the same url.

Are there other types of redirects or causes of the Pagespeed redirect error that I could be missing with these tools? Any suggestions for further troubleshooting this error?

Comment: for www.paytm.ccom I'm getting the same message @Misunderstood might help me here

Answer (score 3):

The page has 5 redirects.  Four of them are caused by Google.

In the image below, the redirects are highlighted in yellow.

The first redirect is the redirect from HTTP to HTTPS

I see nothing technically wrong, I suspect it's a glitch in Google's PageSpeed.

Try removing the 3 double click links and try it again.  If the error goes away then it is just a Google Glitch.  If it does not go away it is still likely just a Google Glitch. 
If it does not go away make a comment to this answer so I can take another look.

You can go here to examine any of the HTTP requests shown in the below image:  https://www.webpagetest.org/result/161009_GS_K14/1/details/#waterfall_view_step1

click on the Request to see the details.

---

Overall your site is in fairly good shape.  That HTTPS 2 second delay is your biggest issue.  There are a few things that could be improved.

---

However you may want to reconsider serving content via https.  All the purple in the bars is SSL negotiation time in a few cases over 0.500 seconds.  The first SSL negotiation in request #2 is quite costly in delaying loading of the index HTML by 2 seconds (request #1 + #2).

**HTTP Response Request #2**

```
Initial Connection: 272 ms
SSL Negotiation: 540 ms
```

If HTTPS is not required it should not be used.  Only uses HTTPS where there is a security exposure risk (e.g. when personal information is submitted).
If you have a valid reason for using HTTPS, then move your site to a server with faster SSL negotiation.  For example look at Google's SSL negotiation time for your .woff font #5:

```
Initial Connection: 31 ms
SSL Negotiation: 44 ms
```

**May Improve Time to First Paint:**
One side bar: Request #5 should be moved up the `<head>`
It is not readily apparent where the two .js requests #3 and #4 
CSS should ALWAYS be loaded before any .js

Move your `<style>` to come right after `<meta http-equiv`

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style id="css">@font-face{font-family:Open Sans; ...
```

---

**A few HTML errors:** 
 https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=https%3A%2F%2Fpaytm.com%2F#l15c3546

Error #1 should be fixed if possible.  The illegal characters probably will not affect Browser performance.  You never want the Browser to go into quirks mode due to an HTML error.

---

**PageSpeed Test review:**
  https://www.webpagetest.org/result/161009_GS_K14/1/performance_optimization/

---

**Scaling Images**
Having the Browser scaling images puts a heavy CPU burden on the Browser.

https://assetscdn.paytm.com/images/catalog/view_item/80197/1475988363969.jpg is resized in HTML or CSS from 1200x707 to 598x352. Serving a scaled image could save 82.8KiB (75% reduction).
https://assetscdn.paytm.com/images/catalog/view_item/77400/1474863992748.jpg is resized in HTML or CSS from 440x234 to 180x109. Serving a scaled image could save 38.6KiB (80% reduction).
https://assetscdn.paytm.com/images/catalog/view_item/78825/1475838256123.jpg is resized in HTML or CSS from 440x234 to 180x109. Serving a scaled image could save 30.5KiB (80% reduction).
https://assetscdn.paytm.com/images/catalog/view_item/75825/1474258437481.jpg is resized in HTML or CSS from 440x234 to 180x109. Serving a scaled image could save 25.3KiB (80% reduction).
https://assetscdn.paytm.com/images/catalog/view_item/69808/1471942064026.jpg is resized in HTML or CSS from 440x234 to 180x109. Serving a scaled image could save 17.4KiB (80% reduction).
https://assetscdn.paytm.com/images/catalog/view_item/69809/1472273404368.jpg is resized in HTML or CSS from 440x234 to 180x109. Serving a scaled image could save 16.4KiB (80% reduction).
https://assetscdn.paytm.com/images/catalog/view_item/69805/1471944601502.jpg is resized in HTML or CSS from 440x234 to 180x109. Serving a scaled image could save 16.4KiB (80% reduction).
https://assetscdn.paytm.com/images/catalog/view_item/80214/1475987326499.jpg is resized in HTML or CSS from 440x234 to 180x109. Serving a scaled image could save 16.0KiB (80% reduction).
https://assetscdn.paytm.com/images/catalog/view_item/79854/1475779273161.jpg is resized in HTML or CSS from 440x234 to 180x109. Serving a scaled image could save 10.2KiB (80% reduction).

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hardwork . Really appreciated . But removing doubleclick links isn't really the issue . Cause this page https://paytm.com/shop/p/samsung-z2-8-gb-red-MOBSAMSUNG-Z2-8JUST22764D686CF36 of our webapp is using the same plugins. and pagespeed works perfectly fine.

This is really an issue as webmaster fetch-and-render functionality breaks for same redirect . Some experts are saying https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pagespeed-insights-discuss/CgaClQ-yDJ8 cookie timestamp might be an issue, but it's not the case for us.

Comment: That was a suggested to do temporarily to confirm if that was source of the "problem".